# Doctrine generate entities includes the schema name in class names

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I generate entities with Doctrine from an existing Postgres Database, the created files are of the form:

- class Public.blog
- class Public.post
- etc

I.e. my database "schema" name is being included in the class name and file name. This then makes the class names illegal due to the ".".

### How can I specify that I do not want the database schema name included in my class names?

Or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

**Extra info**
- The command is fine. My files are created correctly, however the class names are still "Public.blog"
- Symfony2 manages to generate the same files without the Public schema/namespace. So it is possible! However, finding the part of the code that makes this happen is proving difficult!

Comment: can you show us the command that you use in the cli for generating? (suppose it's good but just to be sure)

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm stuck on the same thing

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to temporarily move all my tables into the public schema and generate the entities and crud pages. Then I moved the tables back into place and modified the files in /src/Etc/MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine so that their table: myTable entries were now table: MySchema.myTable.

Then everything worked.